# Where to does macOS's iTunes save iPhone's back data?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

I have done a backup of data from my iPhone to my macOS.

And I don't know where iTunes saved it to on my computer. No notification, no pop ups, just nothing. Just latest backup time. How can I know where my data is on my computer?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On macOS your backups are in `/Users/your username/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup`.

- Open Finder, and select the “Go” menu at the top of the screen. Hold the Option key, and select the “Library” menu option from the Go menu. (On Lion and above, Library will only appear with the Option key held.)
- From Library, navigate to Application Support -> MobileSync -> Backup.

Source (from a blog post I wrote on the topic): https://deciphertools.com/blog/where-are-iphone-backups/

Answer (score 2):

These backups are stored inside:

```
~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup
```

under the form of directories which names end with a timestamp of the backup operation under the form:

```
YYYYMMDD-hhmmss
```

These directories contain a lot of `SQLite 3` database files and a few property list files.

All these files are freely modifiable by the owner i.e. us, thus causing unrecoverable damage to the backups database.
I guess that this is the core reason for Apple to maintain this information secret to us.